# Permissions for posting Unpublished Page Post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, ads-api

I'm upgrading our application from Marketing API v2.2 to work with v2.3.
In v2.2 everything worked fine, but in v2.3 when I try to post unpublished post (with the same user) I get the following error:

> (OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

I use the page access token with the following permissions:
read_stream, read_page_mailboxes, rsvp_event, ads_management, ads_read, read_insights, manage_notifications, manage_pages, publish_actions

I also tried to post with the user's accessToken but it didn't work either.

Comment: Has your app been reviewed by Facebook for the permissions you are asking?

Comment: My app has: email, manage_pages, public_profile, publish_actions, publish_pages, user_friends, Ads Management API Standard Access.

It has the permission publish_actions, which should be enough as far as I know

Comment: Are you sure that on the Status & Review tab of your app's app dashboard you have all of {`publish_actions` (needed to post to pages in v2.2 and below), `publish_pages` (needed to post to pages in v2.3 and above) and `manage_pages` (needed to act as a page and change page settings)} permisisons reviewed and approved? If not, the permissions won't be usable even if a user granted them to your app before v1.0 was removed (unless the token belongs to an admin, developer, tester of your app)

Comment: Er, also, are you sure that the user whose token you're using has granted `publish_pages`? that's the most likely issue if it works in v2.2 but not in v2.3

Comment: Hi @Igy, Thanks a lot for your help. 
The problem was, as you suggested, the missing publish_pages in the user's access token.

Answer (score 1):

*Adding an answer to reflect my comments on the question*

In the case where trying to create a Post on a Page is failing with `(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action` the most likely reason is that the exception text is accurate -

If you have reason to believe otherwise,  you must verify that you have the correct permissions:

- `publish_actions` (if posting to Pages using Graph API v2.2 and below),
- `publish_pages` (if posting to Pages in Graph API v2.3 and above)
- `manage_pages` (needed to act as a page and change page settings)}

You'll need to check that on the `Status & Review` tab of your app's app dashboard your app submitted use of those permissions for review and was approved for use of those permissions, **and** that the user whose token you're using granted those permissions to your app

You may also need to verify that the user whose token you're using has permission to post on the page, but since most posts to pages via the API are done *as* the page (using a [Page Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens)) that's less likely to be the issue